# como recrear la animacion de deslizar el dedo sobre un contenedor y que este se mueva a la derecha o izquierda , y ejecute una accion, en flutter

Tags: flutter, animación

Ya intente con GestureDetector(
onHorizontalDragEnd:
pero no se como dar la animacion.. algo similar a cuando deseamos eliminar un correo desde la aplicacion de gmail

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.